# Wiring an attic light and bathroom light to a 2 gang switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I am trying to wire 2 separate lights to 2 separate switch in one 2 gang switch I'm certain that i've done everything correctly,

The attic light switch works fine, but the bathroom light switch only works when the attic switch is on???

[image: wiring diagram]

Im sure its really simple but it wont work :@

[image: got this from google, im sure its the same as this tho]

Comment: Your diagram is correct. You probably have misinterpreted the labeling on the 2-gang switch. - Can you post a photo of the back of the switch?

Comment: done, although mine has an earth connection aswell,
do the symptoms not suggest anything, it seems odd, possibly a fault switch maybe?

Comment: When you connected the mains hot to the two L1 terminals, did you use a pigtail or did you stuff two wire ends into one L1 screw block?

Answer (score 1):

The switch and the circuit both look dead simple. I can think of two possibilities.

(1) The switch is defective. Alternatively, the switch is not actually broken but is a special application device and it does not function the way we think it does.

You'd need to borrow or buy another switch and connect it the same way. Tell the store where you bought it that you may have a defective product.

(3) You've wired it wrong but you're blind to the error. This happens to me more often than I like to admit. The first person who comes and looks over my shoulder sees immediately what I've done wrong, and looks at me like I was a chimpanzee.

The symptom you describe indicates you may have wired the switch like this:

[image: circuit is just too simple to diagnose]

which is why I asked about pigtailing vs. doubling up on one terminal -- to make you look at the connections from a different perspective.